# node.js mysql push callback

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
   mysql.query('SELECT accountID,deviceID FROM EventData WHERE accountID = "'
       + acc
       + '" AND deviceID = "'
       + deviceID
       + '"  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ',
           function(err,rows,fields) {                   
               if (rows.length > 0) {                 
                   var accountID = rows[0].accountID;
                   var deviceID = rows[0].deviceID;
                   var re2 = ({
                       title: deviceID,                    
                   });                      
                   console.log(re2)
                   console.log("aaa")     
           }
    );
```

The above code produces the following output :

```
   [{ title: 'dev1'}]
   aaa
   [{ title: 'dev2'}]
   aaa
```

But I expected to see the following:

```
   [{ title: 'dev1'},
   { title: 'dev2'}]
   aaa
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, please do not concatenate SQL query strings like that, use the placeholder syntax as it is more secure. Secondly, the code you've currently shown cannot produce the output you've shown, especially since `re2` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't even iterate through the rows, you just added the first title to re2.

This code should work:

```
mysql.query('SELECT accountID,deviceID FROM EventData WHERE accountID = ? AND deviceID = ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1', [acc, deviceID],
       function(err,rows,fields) {
           if (rows.length > 0) { 
               var re2 = [ ];                    
               for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                   re2.push({ title: rows[i].deviceID });
               }                    
               console.log(re2);
               console.log("aaa")  ;
           }   
       }
);
```

Please note that I passed the parameters with placeholders instead of concatenate them explicitly to the string.